# RGB to HSI and HSI to RGB conversion

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to covert `RGB` to `HSI` and revert it. (The task is required to have it from scratch.)

In `RGB` to `HSI` convertion, Saturation and Intensity outputs are fine. But I don't seem to get the problem in the formulation of Hue.
example output:

```
Red = 255, Green = 255, Blue =  255
Hue  = -2147483648, Saturation = 0, Intensity = 255

Red = 252, Green = 255, Blue =  255
Hue  = 3, Saturation = 0.00787402, Intensity = 254
```

I use [this calculator](http://www.had2know.com/technology/hsi-rgb-color-converter-equations.html) to check my outputs.

Please let me know what's wrong. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include "rgb.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char infname[256];
  ofstream outputFile, outputFile2;
  outputFile.open("RGB_HSI.txt");
  outputFile2.open("HSI_RGB.txt");

  cout << "Enter input image  : ";
  cin >> infname;
  IplImage *img = cvLoadImage(infname, 1);
  RgbImage pic(img);
  int H = img->height;
  int W = img->width;

 for (int j=0;j<H;j++) 
 for (int i=0;i<W;i++) {

     double temp = 0;
     double R =(double) pic[j][i].r;
     double G =(double) pic[j][i].g; 
     double B =(double) pic[j][i].b;
     double intensity = 0;
     double hue = 0;
     double saturation = 0;
     int resultHue = 0;
     double resultSaturation = 0;
     int resultIntensity = 0;

   intensity = (R + G + B) / 3;

   if ((R + G + B) == 765) {
      saturation = 0;
      hue = 0;
        }

  double minimum = min(R, min(G, B));

  if (intensity > 0) {
   saturation = 1 - minimum / intensity;
   }

  else if (intensity == 0) {
   saturation = 0;
   }            


  temp = (R - (G/2) - (B/2)) / (sqrt((R*R) + (G*G) + (B*B) - (R*G) - (R*B) - (G*B)));
  if (G >= B) {
    hue = acos(temp); 
    outputFile<<"1. temp = "<<temp<<", H = "<<hue<<endl;
   }

  else if (B > G) {     
    hue = 360 - acos(temp);
    outputFile<<"2. temp = "<<temp<<", H = "<<hue<<endl;
   }

  resultHue = (int) hue;
  resultSaturation = saturation;
  resultIntensity = (int) intensity; 

//outputFile2<<"image = "<<pic[j][i]<<endl;
outputFile<<"Red = "<<R<<", Green = "<<G<<", Blue =  "<<B<<endl;
outputFile<<"Hue  = "<<resultHue<<", Saturation = "<<resultSaturation<<", Intensity = "<<resultIntensity<<endl;



//converting HSI to RGB

int backR = 0, backG = 0, backB = 0;

if (resultHue == 0){
   backR = (int) (resultIntensity + (2 * resultIntensity * resultSaturation));
   backG = (int) (resultIntensity - (resultIntensity * resultSaturation));
   backB = (int) (resultIntensity - (resultIntensity * resultSaturation));
  }

else if ((0 < resultHue) && (resultHue < 120)) {
   backR = (int) (resultIntensity + (resultIntensity * resultSaturation) * cos(resultHue) / cos(60-resultHue));
   backG = (int) (resultIntensity + (resultIntensity * resultSaturation) * (1 - cos(resultHue) / cos(60-resultHue)));
   backB = (int) (resultIntensity - (resultIntensity * resultSaturation));
  }

else if ( resultHue == 120 ){
   backR = (int) (resultIntensity - (resultIntensity * resultSaturation));
   backG = (int) (resultIntensity + (2 * resultIntensity * resultSaturation));
   backB = (int) (resultIntensity - (resultIntensity * resultSaturation));
  }

else if ((120 < resultHue) && (resultHue < 240)) {
   backR = (int) (resultIntensity - (resultIntensity * resultSaturation));
   backG = (int) (resultIntensity + (resultIntensity * resultSaturation) * cos(resultHue-120) / cos(180-resultHue));
   backB = (int) (resultIntensity + (resultIntensity * resultSaturation) * (1 - cos(resultHue-120) / cos(180-resultHue)));
  }

else if (resultHue == 240) {
   backR = (int) (resultIntensity - (resultIntensity * resultSaturation));
   backG = (int) (resultIntensity - (resultIntensity * resultSaturation));
   backB = (int) (resultIntensity + (2 * resultIntensity * resultSaturation));
  }

else if ((240 < resultHue) && (resultHue < 360)) {
   backR = (int) (resultIntensity + (resultIntensity * resultSaturation) * (1 - cos(resultHue-240) / cos(300-resultHue)));
   backG = (int) (resultIntensity - (resultIntensity * resultSaturation));
   backB = (int) (resultIntensity + (resultIntensity * resultSaturation) * cos(resultHue-240) / cos(300-resultHue));
  }

//outputpic[j][i] = (int) (R + G + B); 
//outputFile2<<"output = "<<outputpic[j][i]<<endl;
outputFile2<<"Hue  = "<<resultHue<<", Saturation = "<<resultSaturation<<", Intensity = "<<resultIntensity<<endl;
outputFile2<<"Red = "<<backR<<", Green = "<<backG<<", Blue =  "<<backB<<endl;
}


outputFile.close();
cout << "\nRGB_HSI values printed as text file: RGB_HSI.text\n";
outputFile2.close();
cout << "\nHSI_RGB values printed as text file: HSI_RGB.text\n";

   return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You should correct your indentation. It will enable people to focus on your question more than trying to understand your code.

Comment: The number -2147483648 suggests that you have an issue with signed/unsigned integers (or possibly casting NaN/inf to int.)

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: here where i'm getting problems at.                             temp = (R - (G/2) - (B/2)) / (sqrt((R*R) + (G*G) + (B*B) - (R*G) - (R*B) - (G*B)));
  if (G >= B) {
    hue = acos(temp); 
    outputFile<<"1. temp = "<<temp<<", H = "<<hue<<endl;
   }

  else if (B > G) {     
    hue = 360 - acos(temp);
    outputFile<<"2. temp = "<<temp<<", H = "<<hue<<endl;
   }

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
temp = (R - (G/2) - (B/2)) / (sqrt((R*R) + (G*G) + (B*B) - (R*G) - (R*B) - (G*B)));
```

When `R = G = B`, then you have a division by zero:

```
R² - G² - B² - RG - RB - GB = R² + R² + R² - R² - R² - R² = 0
```

*I'm actually surprised it didn't crashed...*

In that case, just assign 0 to the hue. From your link:

> Neutral colors--white, gray, and black--are set to 0° for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

From others answer it looks like there is a divide by zero issue when `R = G = B` when you calculate `temp` but also from what I can tell you are using `degree`s with the trigonometric function but they are expecting `radian`s i.e.:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   double pi = atan(1)*4 ;
   std::cout << cos(180) << std::endl ;
   std::cout << cos(360) << std::endl ;
   std::cout << cos(pi) << std::endl ;
   std::cout << cos(2*pi) << std::endl ;   
}
```