# Converting HSI back to RGB

Tags: python, rgb

So i am trying to average out the intensity of an image.
Hence, what I have done is convert the original image into HSI, find the average intensity of the original image, and then modify the intensity of the HSI image before converting it back to RGB.
however, I am currently facing an issue with converting HSI back into RGB

```
def HSI_TO_RGB(Average, img):
     with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):

        #Load image with 32 bit floats as variable type
        bgr = np.float32(img)/255

        #Separate color channels
        blue = bgr[:,:,0]
        green = bgr[:,:,1]
        red = bgr[:,:,2]

        #Calculate Saturation
        def calc_saturation(red, blue, green):
            minimum = np.minimum(np.minimum(red, green), blue)
            saturation = 1 - (3 / (red + green + blue + 0.001) * minimum)

            return saturation

        #Calculate Hue
        def calc_hue(red, blue, green):
            hue = np.copy(red)

            for i in range(0, blue.shape[0]):
                for j in range(0, blue.shape[1]):
                    hue[i][j] = 0.5 * ((red[i][j] - green[i][j]) + (red[i][j] - blue[i][j])) / \
                                math.sqrt((red[i][j] - green[i][j])**2 +
                                        ((red[i][j] - blue[i][j]) * (green[i][j] - blue[i][j])))
                    hue[i][j] = math.acos(hue[i][j])

                    if blue[i][j] <= green[i][j]:
                        hue[i][j] = hue[i][j]
                    else:
                        hue[i][j] = ((360 * math.pi) / 180.0) - hue[i][j]

            return hue

        huehue = calc_hue(red, blue, green) * 255
        satsat = calc_saturation(red, blue, green) * 255

        for huehue in range(0,1):
           backR =  (Average + (2 * Average * satsat))
           backG =  (Average - (Average * satsat))
           backB =  (Average - (Average * satsat))
           final = cv2.merge((backR, backG, backB))
           return final

        for huehue in range(1,120):
           backR = (int) (Average + (Average * satsat) * cos(huehue) / cos(60-huehue))
           backG = (int) (Average + (Average * satsat) * (1 - cos(huehue) / cos(60-huehue)))
           backB = (int) (Average - (Average * satsat))
           final = cv2.merge((backR, backG, backB))
           return final
        for huehue in range(120,121):
           backR = (int) (Average - (Average * satsat))
           backG = (int) (Average + (2 * Average * satsat))
           backB = (int) (Average - (Average * satsat))
           final = cv2.merge((backR, backG, backB))
           return final
        for huehue in range(121,240):
           backR = (int) (Average - (Average * satsat))
           backG = (int) (Average + (Average * satsat) * cos(huehue-120) / cos(180-huehue))
           backB = (int) (Average + (Average * satsat) * (1 - cos(huehue-120) / cos(180-huehue)))
           final = cv2.merge((backR, backG, backB))
           return final
        for huehue in range(240,241):
           backR = (int) (Average - (Average * satsat))
           backG = (int) (Average - (Average * satsat))
           backB = (int) (Average + (2 * Average * satsat))
           final = cv2.merge((backR, backG, backB))
           return final
        for huehue in range(241,360): 
           backR = (int) (Average + (Average * satsat) * (1 - cos(huehue-240) / cos(300-huehue)))
           backG = (int) (Average - (Average * satsat))
           backB = (int) (Average + (Average * satsat) * cos(huehue-240) / cos(300-huehue))
           final = cv2.merge((backR, backG, backB))
           return final

        final=final/360*255
        return final
```

I mainly adapted this code from >[RGB to HSI and HSI to RGB conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463668/rgb-to-hsi-and-hsi-to-rgb-conversion)<
and I have tried to normalize the values to 0-255 but I am returned with this instead.
[image]
can anyone give me some advice on how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues, and I am not sure I managed to correct all of them:

- You are using `for` instead of `if`, for example:
  `for huehue in range(1,120)` supposed to be `if 1 <= huehue_deg[i][j] < 120`.
- You are mixing degrees and radians:
  The function `math.cos` uses radians as input.
  You are using it with degrees: `cos(60-huehue)`
  On the other hand, `calc_hue` returns hue in radians, and you are using `range(1,120)` as degrees.
- You are mixing RGB and BGR:
  At the beginning: `blue = bgr[:,:,0]`
  At the end: `final = cv2.merge((backR, backG, backB))`
- You are multiplying by 255 too early:
  `huehue = calc_hue(red, blue, green) * 255` and `satsat = calc_saturation(red, blue, green) * 255` are not it place.
- It is unclear from your post what is `Average` argument.
  I assumed it is the average of RGB after converting to `float32` (range [0, 1]).

The following (corrected) code reads input image, passes it to `HSI_TO_RGB` and displays the output:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
from math import cos, radians

def HSI_TO_RGB(Average, img):
     with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):

        #Load image with 32 bit floats as variable type
        bgr = np.float32(img)/255

        #Separate color channels
        blue = bgr[:,:,0]
        green = bgr[:,:,1]
        red = bgr[:,:,2]

        #Calculate Saturation
        def calc_saturation(red, blue, green):
            minimum = np.minimum(np.minimum(red, green), blue)
            saturation = 1 - (3 / (red + green + blue + 0.001) * minimum)

            return saturation

        #Calculate Hue
        def calc_hue(red, blue, green):
            hue = np.copy(red)

            for i in range(0, blue.shape[0]):
                for j in range(0, blue.shape[1]):
                    hue[i][j] = 0.5 * ((red[i][j] - green[i][j]) + (red[i][j] - blue[i][j])) / \
                                math.sqrt((red[i][j] - green[i][j])**2 +
                                        ((red[i][j] - blue[i][j]) * (green[i][j] - blue[i][j])))
                    hue[i][j] = math.acos(hue[i][j])

                    if blue[i][j] <= green[i][j]:
                        hue[i][j] = hue[i][j]
                    else:
                        hue[i][j] = ((360 * math.pi) / 180.0) - hue[i][j]

            return hue

        huehue = calc_hue(red, blue, green) # * 255
        satsat = calc_saturation(red, blue, green) # * 255

        huehue = np.nan_to_num(huehue)  # Replace nan with zeros

        # Convert from radians to degrees
        huehue_deg = np.rad2deg(huehue)

        # Initiazlie with zeros
        backR = np.zeros_like(satsat)
        backG = np.zeros_like(satsat)
        backB = np.zeros_like(satsat)

        for i in range(0, satsat.shape[0]):
            for j in range(0, satsat.shape[1]):

                if 0 <= huehue_deg[i][j] < 1:
                   backR[i][j] =  (Average[i][j] + (2 * Average[i][j] * satsat[i][j]))
                   backG[i][j] =  (Average[i][j] - (Average[i][j] * satsat[i][j]))
                   backB[i][j] =  (Average[i][j] - (Average[i][j] * satsat[i][j]))                   

                elif 1 <= huehue_deg[i][j] < 120:
                   backR[i][j] = (Average[i][j] + (Average[i][j] * satsat[i][j]) * cos(huehue[i][j]) / cos(radians(60)-huehue[i][j]))
                   backG[i][j] = (Average[i][j] + (Average[i][j] * satsat[i][j]) * (1 - cos(huehue[i][j]) / cos(radians(60)-huehue[i][j])))
                   backB[i][j] = (Average[i][j] - (Average[i][j] * satsat[i][j]))

                elif 120 <= huehue_deg[i][j] < 121:
                   backR[i][j] = (Average[i][j] - (Average[i][j] * satsat[i][j]))
                   backG[i][j] = (Average[i][j] + (2 * Average[i][j] * satsat[i][j]))
                   backB[i][j] = (Average[i][j] - (Average[i][j] * satsat[i][j]))

                elif 121 <= huehue_deg[i][j] < 240:
                   backR[i][j] = (Average[i][j] - (Average[i][j] * satsat[i][j]))
                   backG[i][j] = (Average[i][j] + (Average[i][j] * satsat[i][j]) * cos(huehue[i][j]-radians(120)) / cos(radians(180)-huehue[i][j]))
                   backB[i][j] = (Average[i][j] + (Average[i][j] * satsat[i][j]) * (1 - cos(huehue[i][j]-radians(120)) / cos(radians(180)-huehue[i][j])))

                elif 240 <= huehue_deg[i][j] < 241:
                   backR[i][j] = (Average[i][j] - (Average[i][j] * satsat[i][j]))
                   backG[i][j] = (Average[i][j] - (Average[i][j] * satsat[i][j]))
                   backB[i][j] = (Average[i][j] + (2 * Average[i][j] * satsat[i][j]))

                else: #elif 241 <= huehue_deg[i][j] < 360:
                   backR[i][j] = (Average[i][j] + (Average[i][j] * satsat[i][j]) * (1 - cos(huehue[i][j]-radians(240)) / cos(radians(300)-huehue[i][j])))
                   backG[i][j] = (Average[i][j] - (Average[i][j] * satsat[i][j]))
                   backB[i][j] = (Average[i][j] + (Average[i][j] * satsat[i][j]) * cos(huehue[i][j]-radians(240)) / cos(radians(300)-huehue[i][j]))

        #final = cv2.merge((backR, backG, backB))

        # The correct order is BGR and not RGB (at the beginning of the funtion: blue = bgr[:,:,0])
        final = cv2.merge((backB, backG, backR))

        #final = final/360*255

        # Convert from flot32 to uint8:
        final = np.round(final * 255).astype(np.uint8)
        return final


##### Converting to HSI using OpenCV is simple, converting back is difficult #####
def bgr2hsi(bgr):
    """Convert image from BGR color format to HSI color format"""
    # Convert from BGR to HSV using OpenCV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # Difference between HSV and HSI:
    # In HSV: V = max(R, G, B)
    # In HSI: I = (R + G + B)/3
    hsi = hsv
    hsi[:, :, 2] = np.mean(bgr, 2)

    return hsi


bgr = cv2.imread('tree.png')

#hsi = bgr2hsi(bgr)

average = np.mean(np.float32(bgr)/255, 2)
new_bgr = HSI_TO_RGB(average, bgr)

cv2.imshow('new_bgr', new_bgr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Note:
I didn't try to optimize the performance and I wasn't looking for existing implementation of RGB to HSI.
I just tried to correct the code you have posted.

---

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi thanks alot for the answer, didnt realise those details before as i am still new to coding, appreciate it!